# Bootstrap dropdown menu conflict jQuery 1.11.3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap 3.3.2 with jQuery 1.11.3 and the dropdown menu is not working. If I downgrade to jQuery 1.8.3 it's working fine, and I don't understand why. Only the jQuery version changing.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="hu">
<head>
    <title>title</title>
    <meta charset="iso-8859-2">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/bootstrap/js/dropdown.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header" class="col-md-12">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid"><div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul id="menubox" class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false" href="#">Blog</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="...">New</a></li>
                            <li><a href="...">Search</a></li>
                            <li><a href="...">List</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="...">Help</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="...">Menus</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</body>
```

The console error log is empty. Any idea?

Comment: Did you test it in other browsers?

Comment: yes, Chrome and Firefox too

Comment: What is the content of your `bootstrap/js/dropdown.js` file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to load the jquery and Bootstrap files from CDN.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

If this works, then your files aren't loading properly or are corrupted